# apache reverse proxy in docker

Tags: apache, docker, jenkins, proxy, reverse-proxy

I am currently trying to learn to use docker and I ran into a small problem with reverse proxy and apache.

So I have a container running jenkins/jenkins:latest on port 8080 and I want to map it to /jenkins on port 80 with apache. This is my current proxy config:

```
ProxyPass         /jenkins  http://jenkins:8080/jenkins nocanon
ProxyPassReverse  /jenkins  http://jenkins:8080/jenkins
ProxyRequests     Off
AllowEncodedSlashes NoDecode
```

And with this it redirects the first request to the jenkins container but jenkins redirects to /login which causes a 404.
I understand why this is happening, but is there any way of solving this without modifying the jenkins image by setting a prefix on it?

The main reason for why I don't want to add a prefix is because it seems like a lot of work, especially if I need to do that for all services that I want to run in docker... It just seems very impractical.

Answer (score 0):

The [Docker hub page for Jenkins](https://hub.docker.com/_/jenkins/) does not mention the /jenkins suffix. Did you tried with simply with following setup?

```
ProxyPass         /  http://jenkins:8080/ nocanon
ProxyPassReverse  /  http://jenkins:8080/
ProxyRequests     Off
AllowEncodedSlashes NoDecode
```

Comment: It was a while ago since I looked at this :) but I don't think that your solution would have solved my problems as it reverses everything to jenkins. If I remember correctly I wanted the reverse proxy so that I could host multiple applications... but you are right that it should work otherwise